# How to restore mdf file in sql server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

I have a `.MDF` file and no `.LDF` files for a database created in SQL Server 2005. When I try to attach the `.MDF` file to a different SQL Server, I get the following error message.

I would like to accomplish any one of the following options:

Attach the database without data loss (unlikely but would save me some time).
Attach the database with data loss (whatever transactions were open are lost).
Recover the schema only (no data) from the `.MDF` file.

What SQL commands can I try to get my database going again?

Comment: **what** error message?!?!? I don't see anything .....

Answer (score 4):

You can use [sp_attach_single_file_db](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174385(v=sql.90).aspx) or the newer version [CREATE DATABASE database_name FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061(v=sql.90).aspx).  In both cases it will create a new log file for you.

Unfortunately because you have no log you will not be able to recover anything that has not been committed.  It is also a good idea to run a DBCC CHECKDB afterwards to make sure there is no other damage.

Comment: Slight correction: you will not be able to recover anything that has not been committed *and checkpointed to the data file*. There's no guarantee that you have a physically or logically consistent database if you don't have the transaction log. It's probably better than nothing, though.

Comment: Excellent point.  And a backup would be a much better solution, but you do what you can.

Answer (score 0):

Here are details that cover parts 2) and 3) in case re-creating log doesn’t work which can happen if MDF file is corrupted.

You can recover data and structure only by reading MDF file with some third party tool that can de-code what’s written as binary data but even with such tools you can’t always do the job completely.

In such cases you can try SQL Server Restore Toolbox. From what I know this is the only tool that can do this kind of job but it’s quite expensive.

> http://www.sqlserver.restoretools.com/

Much better idea is to try to recover these from any old backups if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said, have .mdf file only.  You can still attach your database without ldf file. You just need to run following commands:

Method 1:

```
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='Database_Name',
@physname=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Database_Name.mdf'
GO
```

As suggested above.

Method 2:

```
CREATE DATABASE Database_Name ON
(FILENAME =N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Database_Name.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```

It will create log file for you.